# How do I run an existing Django file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, server, terminal

I downloaded a folder with multiple python files in the form of a Django project for a course and I am unable to run it. Usually, when you create a Django project it is created within the terminal with the line `django-admin startproject web_project .` and then `python manage.py migrate` is used and then the line `python manage.py runserver` to start a server.

How do I start a server to run my project?

When I use `django-admin startproject web_project .`, it creates a new project which I don't want. When I use `python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py runserver` it says:

```
Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
```

But even when I used `python3 manage.py migrate` or `python3 manage.py runserver` instead and it returned:

```
python3: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you at the right level in the folder hierarchy?

Comment: What do you mean? Do I have to open up the folder that the project is in within the terminal?

Comment: Yes, you need to go to the directory that contains the manage.py.

Comment: How do I do that through the terminal?

Comment: Using `cd` is a safe bet.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first make sure you opened command prompt or terminal in right directory(in projects directory) when you are running the runserver command.
If you are on windows open the project folder(the folder that contains files like manage.py), then right click and press open PowerShell window here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

first of all I recommend creating a virtual environment using the following command

```
python3 -m venv .env
```

then activate it
source .env/bin/activate
"django-admin statproject" its for initalite a new project for running an excited Django app you should just install Django - if there is now "requirements.txt" file- , migrate and run.

```
pip install Django
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
```